# Add Here not Visible in Placeholder in Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor, placeholders

I have a scenario where the `Add Here` button is not visible for the `placeholder` I want to add a component to. I have to select other content in the placeholder and use the `Go to parent component` button to navigate back up to my placeholder. At that point, the appropriate `Add Here` button is visible and I can add a component.

Two notes I think are important, the existing visible items in the placeholder are all at least grandchild descendants of the placeholder in question (they are within other nested placeholders). Also, if I do add a component to the placeholder (a direct child of my placeholder) I at least get an `Add Here` button directly above the added component but not between any of the other components that make up the nested placeholders.

An image might help explain this better:

[image]

**A:** The placeholder I want to add a component too but essentially, I can't select this placeholder - no `Add Here` button shows up.

**B:** Component that is already within the placeholder. It has a placeholder of its own, D.

**C.** Component that is already within the placeholder. It has a placeholder of its own, E.

To add another component to A, I have to select content in D or E and use the `Go to parent component` button to navigate back to A. At that point, the `Add Here` button shows up and I can add a component to A.

What experience editor magic can I do to get the `Add Here` button show up in placeholder A (instead of only placeholders D and E) when the add component button is clicked in the ribbon?

Comment: I think your question has been answered in http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/612/component-not-showing-as-an-option-to-add-to-a-placeholder. If that link doesn't help you - try Placeholder Settings or this link: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/336/how-to-make-experience-editor-placeholders-editable-without-placeholder-settings

Comment: This sounds like the expected behavior to me.  Do the buttons show when you click the New Component button in the ribbon?

Comment: based on the comments, I wasn't explaining this well. I've added some clarifications and an image to illustrate what is going on.

Comment: Can you confirm that the placeholder you are trying to add a component to, has the Editable selected as pointed by Mark on one of his links?

Comment: @Diego, it does. I can add components to it, the issue is, I have to select content from placeholders D or E from the image and then use "Go to parent component" button to navigate up to placeholder A for the "Add Here" button show up in placeholder A. Why is there no "Add Here" button show up in placeholder A by default when trying to add a component from the ribbon?

Comment: that's weird. Can you click on the View tab on the top and check whether the "Editing" checkbox is checked?
Also when you click on the tab Home and "Components" do you see any javascripts error on the console?
Last but not least, sitecore logs show you anything useful? Errors, duplicate entries, etc. I've seen Sitecore out of the box interface not function properly and the cause of it was on the logs

Comment: Could it also be something in the design of your page is layering the Add Here buttons, so when you click Components and see all of the buttons, the one you want is obfuscated? If so, maybe adding some spacing in edit mode would help. You could also add some custom framing - I know this is out there: https://citizensitecore.com/2016/01/27/taming-the-experience-editor-customizing-placeholders/ - and I think in the last unofficial Sitecore training another method was demoed that will be written on soon.

Comment: Are any special or custom dynamic placeholders in question?  I've replicated your exact scenario in a sandbox environment, and the "Component New" button in the Experience Editor ribbon displays all "Add Here"'s as expected.

Comment: I agree with @MarkCassidy on this. We saw a similar issue at a client project, where the client had unchecked the 'editable' option. By checking it, things got back to normal.

Answer (score 6):

Sitecore really should ship with some CSS to make sure that placeholders don't shrink to 0px width.  I've had this numerous times, and you can't click on something that's 0px wide.

Try adding this to your site's css

```
.scEmptyPlaceholder { min-width: 100px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

I once faced a similar issue where the 'Add Here' was not visible for a component (I can't remember whether it was the top-most one or the out-most one).
I had to add an empty div in the containing view where the main placeholder was declared.

So in your case, component A is rendered in placeholder Z for example. Placeholder Z was created/declared inside a view that contained nothing except the declaration of the placeholder. I had to add an empty div around this placeholder declaration which fixed it for me.

**Before fix:**

```
@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("...")
```

**After fix:**

```
<div>
@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("...")
</div>
```

I really hope this your case!

Comment: +1 while not precisely as your answer, turns out that surrounding HTML elements (and their CSS) can indeed affect the display of the component/handles

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar issue. If the Sitecore component has 'position : fixed' style, in that case, if the component is added on the top of the page, it disappears from the Experience Editor. Here is a good article about this issue [Positioning a fixed header below the Sitecore Experience Editor ribbon](https://blog.richardszalay.com/2017/03/24/sitecore-experience-ribbon-header/)

Comment: You should provide details of what's in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Every time when I work with placeholders I try to wrap them in custom style which appears only in Experience editor. It helps content editors understand where is the edge of placeholder and help to select nested placeholders. Example below.

```
@model Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel
@{
    string style = "";
    if (!Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsNormal && Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor)
    {
        style = "min-height:200px; min-width:100px; border:1px dotted black; background-color: hotpink; padding-bottom:15px";
    }
}
<section class="some-class" style="@style">
    @Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("your-placeholder", CreatePlaceholderWrapper(), 2, 4)
</section>
@functions
{
    TagBuilder CreatePlaceholderWrapper()
    {
        var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("div");
        tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("style", "min-width:200px; min-height:100px; border:1px dotted black; background-color: pink;");
        return tagBuilder;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced this issue recently. It was because an HTML data source had `<br>` instead of `<br/>`.

I changed it and the issue was resolved.